# Workflow fails to write REST call to Workflow History as log

Tags: 2013, workflow, rest, log

I am trying to start a workflow from a Sharepoint Designer 2013 workflow via the REST API, and am logging to the Workflow History list in order to debug it. Trying to log the following string, however:

```
> https://{server}/{site}/_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowInstanceService.Current/StartWorkflowOnListItemBySubscriptionId(subscriptionId='caa09cae-3955-4c26-bb7e-24b4a95294b0',itemId='e9527d1f-df26-4c77-aa95-c92ee350547b')
```

Causes the logging action to fail and the workflow to be cancelled with the following unintelligable error message:

> RequestorId: 8803c5ad-905e-e4be-861f-24ab01baf2f2. Details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 500 {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["34"],"SPRequestGuid":["ccb2c0a8-0fad-4830-8701-65c7756a1ab9"],"request-id":["ccb2c0a8-0fad-4830-8701-65c7756a1ab9"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4569"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1; RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Thu, 11 Feb 2016 07:04:02 GMT"],"Set-Cookie":["WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated={b03c5a6d-91e3-4648-af94-cd72742566da}; path=/; secure"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.5"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]} at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Note if I replace the call 'StartWorkflowOnListItemBySubscriptionId' with something else, or I spell it incorrectly, then it will log just fine. Does anyone know why it is doing this??